# I want create check inside while from db

Tags: php

I want to create check inside while from DB

```
while($import = $query->fetch_array()) {
   $userid = $import['userid'];
   $amount = $import['amount'];
   
   if($userid > 1) {
         $amount++;
     }
}
```

I have operations table in db and I want If the userid is repeated more than once, I want to add the old amount + the new amount to userid with not repeating more than once

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) first... this question is far too abstract and vague (the database is completely unknown to us). How shall one be able to answer that?

Comment: You should do it in SQL if possible

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it's worked.

```
<?php 
    $amount = 0;
    while($import = $query->fetch_array()) {
        if($import['userid'] > 1) {
            $amount =  $amount + $import['amount'];
        }
        else {
            $amount =  $import['amount'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [];

while($import = $query->fetch_array()) {
   $userid = $import['userid'];
   $amount = $import['amount'];
   
   if($userid > 1) {
      if(!array_key_exists($userid, $arr)) {
         $arr[$userid] = 0;
      }
      $arr[$userid] += $amount;
   }
}
```